# .bat script doesn't work by using window scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

i created a .bat script to perform daily folder compression. it is working fine when i double click the .bat file. However, it doesnt work when i include it in window scheduler.

Below is the script:

```
rem ****************************
rem ** To create back up file **
rem ****************************
"C:\Program Files\WinZip\WINZIP32.EXE" -a -r -p "E:\Backup\Daily\sst.zip" "P:\SST\*.*"
```

When i run it via window scheduler, the status is always "running" but nothing is generated. Can someone explain the situation?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19706547/1768141) and also make sure you've set the correct credentials.

Comment: With default settings task scheduler should show cmd window atleast in Windows 7. Try add pause after command line zip in bat file. Also select  checkbox "Run with highest privileges" in task scheduler. You can also try to run it without bat file using arguments in task scheduler.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I tried both suggestions but with no luck. The task keep showing "running" but nothing is created.

Comment: Does the user you're assigning this task to have a password? I had similar problems while configuring backup scripts for some of my clients, and (after some struggle) I discovered that **the scheduler would not execute the tasks if the user had no password**.